# How do I validate a GitHub repository name?

Tags: backstage

I would like to enforce a naming convention when a component is created by a software template. In my template.yaml, the `pattern` regex works as expected on the input string for component name, but the same regex doesn't work on the input string of the repoURL. How do you validate and enforce a naming convention on a new repository created by the scaffolder?

https://backstage.io/docs/features/software-templates/input-examples#simple-input-with-basic-validations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by removing the input fields for the repository name and setting the `repoUrl:` to the component name that gets validated correctly with the `pattern` feature.

```yaml
repoUrl: github.com?owner=owner&repo=${{ parameters.name }}
```